# [Java; Spring]. Store a data before mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm currently working on *Java* project based on *Spring framework* and I faced an issue.

Basicly, I wanna store a global data for any user (newby / permanent) once they enter the web-site.
You may think about a simple Java's static variable, but moreover I'm interested in changing some variable's value for some kind of users.

For Example: Each user have variable `language = "ENG"` once they enter my site (just forget about the cookies). `User1` may change itself variable to `language = "OTHER_LANG"` while `User2` is still have `language = "ENG"`.

So, the quesion is: how to set this default global variable to all site visitors?

Comment: You might look into springs session handling. A session stores information for each connection (or user) individually.

Comment: Sessions are definitely a good way to store information about users in memory if you need to do so. One reason is that there's already functionality in place to remove stale sessions. When creating a session or try to retrieve the language for the first time you could just initialize it to your default. However, note that if your application tends to have a lot of concurrent users all those sessions will eat up a lot of memory and high availability setups are more complex, so why not just put the language into a cookie? That would be stored more long-term as well.